# "Start Performance Analysis" button missing on Nsight + Visual Studio

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2017, nsight

I am usually debug my kernel and check timing with "Start Performance Analysis" Button.
It shows When I used CUDA 10.2, RTX Titan V.

[image]

But, That button now shown since I upgraded CUDA version to 11.3.
Here is my current visual studio options. And I am using Visual Studio 2017, CUDA 11.3, RTX 3090 now.
Do you guys know why those options disappeared on VS2017?
And how to restore those button on my environment?

[image]

// Edit : I confused the name of button. Sorry //

Comment: @RobertCrovella Oh. I took a mistake on the question. I'm so sorry. I look forward "Start Performance Analysis" button.

Comment: That feature has been removed as indicated in the release notes [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/release-notes/index.html#nsight-vse-new).  "Integrated CUDA profiling, deprecated since NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition 2019.2, has been removed from the Performance Analysis tools and replaced by: Nsight Compute for Volta and later family GPUs nvprof and Visual Profiler for Pascal and early family GPUs (not participating tools for NVIDIA Nsight Integration)"  You're expected to switch to the new profiling tools, e.g. nsight compute/nsight systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature has been removed as indicated in the release notes [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/release-notes/index.html#nsight-vse-new):

> "Integrated CUDA profiling, deprecated since NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition 2019.2, has been removed from the Performance Analysis tools and replaced by: Nsight Compute for Volta and later family GPUs nvprof and Visual Profiler for Pascal and early family GPUs (not participating tools for NVIDIA Nsight Integration)"

So, you're expected to switch to [the new profiling tools](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/migrating-nvidia-nsight-tools-nvvp-nvprof/), e.g. [nsight compute](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-nsight-compute-to-inspect-your-kernels/)/[nsight systems](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/transitioning-nsight-systems-nvidia-visual-profiler-nvprof/) for newer GPUs (Volta and forward, roughly speaking), or else one of [the legacy profilers](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html) such as `nvprof` or the visual profiler, for older GPUs.

I suppose another option is to revert to the older version of the Nsight VSE tool, depending on your CUDA version needs.